# How to handle database table with around 400 million records?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table with 400 million records with 5 columns.
statsid (primary ke), date,time,eventtype,pubid(clustered index)

when I run query in Microsoft management studio like "select count(1) from table name" it is taking around 1 hour after this I tried to rebuild index but it is throwing error like "collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" please help me why this is taking so much time to execute simple select query.

Comment: Check the estimated query plan (CTRL-L). Is it using an index? Does it recommend an index? Is that the only query you want to optimise?

Comment: thanks for your reply yes query is using index pubid but it is taking so long time.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(1)` returns number of rows in the table. To calculate this number the server has to scan (read) the whole table (or index). This is what you see in the plan. I'm afraid, there is no magic way to make it fast. The server has to read all 400M rows.

Comment: Depending on your access level you could just use     sp_spaceused 'table_name'